# Image Gallery and Dialogue Box using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an image gallery which will be displayed as grid, but when i click on that image i need a dialogue box with that image and text fields with image title and author..

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/logeshhy/Material-UI-ImageGallery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you save the selected tile instead of the boolean whether the dialog is open or not? And if you have a selected tile, you display the content within the dialog?

I modified your sandbox to reflect that: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cache-75sns

Comment: If that answered your question, could you mark it as accepte so others can find it as well? Glad I could help

Comment: Worked like a charm. Had problems for transition with Ts - check documentation here https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/